# Synchronous completion of AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call within another AJAX call.

I am using `$.ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/xx/xxx',
    success: function (data) {
        if(data == true){
            var j = MethodThatCallAjaxFunction();
            //some code here
        }
    }    
});
```

How can I ensure the value of `j` is filled before I execute code after the comment `//some code here`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  `MethodeThatCallAjaxFunction` can either by syncrhonous (bad), or you can attach a callback to it.

```
function mtcaf() {
    return $.ajax();
}
//snip
if (data == true) {
    mtcaf().done(function () {
        //some codes here
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer if you keep the code structure as the OP's code though. After all there's nothing intrinsically wrong with it ;)

Comment: How will i get the value returned by mtcaf in the main method?

Comment: I know, I just didn't feel like writing out `MethodeThatCallAjaxFunction` repeatedly .. maybe that's how I was able to answer faster.

Comment: @user444569 you can't, and you won't.  That's not how ajax works.